# Ransack with association and through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have following models

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :B
  has_many :C, through: :B
end

I am trying to do a ransack search on A 

A.ransack(
  c_name_in: 'term',
  b_name_in: 'another_term'
)
```

The issue is it is doing left outer join with table b twice.

Here is a hand-written sql to illustrate the point

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN c ON c.a_id = a.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON b.id = c.b_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN c association_c ON association_c.a_id = a.id
WHERE (b.name ILIKE '%term%' AND association_c.name IN ILIKE '%anotherterm%'
```

Any ideas how to tackle this?